# Compare two CSV files with Jmeter

Tags: file, csv, compare, jmeter

How can I compare two CSV files and retrieve all the differences with jmeter?

For example, if i have 2 csv files like that:

- first:

  ```
  a
  b
  c
  ```
- second:

  ```
   a
   f
   b
   d
   c
  ```

I want to catch the differences between the 2 files.
Here i want: `f` and `d`.

How can i do that with Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not the right tool to do diff.
You should do this before the test and create a CSV for that.

Comment: Can't you do the data preparation before the Test run ?